# I have to read data from csv file and perform math operation (sum, avg, min, max) of each row data (rows can be infinite and columns can be infinite)

Tags: java, csv

import java.util.Scanner;
public class csv_demo
{
    //  private static final Exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException = null;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        //Get scanner instance
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Glocation/Desktop/abc.csv"));
        //Set the delimiter used in file
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");

        int sum = 0, avg =0,max = 0,min = 0,a=0,b=0;

        System.out.println("N1|N2|Sum|Avg|Max|Min");

     try
     {
       while(scanner.hasNext())
       {    
           String line=scanner.nextLine();
           String[] arr=line.split(",");

           for(int k=0;k<arr.length-1;k++)
           {
               a=Integer.parseInt(arr[k]);
               b=Integer.parseInt(arr[k+1]);

               sum = a+b;

                avg= a+b/2;
                if(a>b) 
                {
                    max=a;
                    min=b;
                }
                else
                {
                    max=b;
                    min=a;
                }
                System.out.println(a+"  |"+b+"  |"+sum+"  |"+avg+"  |"+max+"  |"+min);
           }
            }
     }catch (Exception e)
     {    }
    }
 }
```

I am getting error in the line of converting string array to get value in variable "a". 
My CSV file is 
1 2
3 4
6 7
9 2 5 7 
5 6   8

Comment: Summing of infinite columns is an interesting problem. I suppose one would have to work out whether the values represented a convergent series, and then use series summing techniques to calculate the answer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Where do you see the AIOOBE occurring?

Comment: shruti You have a CSV with whitespace delimited lines and yet you split that using ","? Does this make sense to you?

Comment: My csv file is already with column and row separated.  Looking same like Excel file. row col = [1][1] = 8 [1][2]= 9  [2][1] = 10 [2][2]= 8  [3][1] = 5 [3][2]= 7  [3][3] = 8 [4][2]= 4.

Comment: You're trying to read "," delimited stuff and your CSV doesn't seem to contain such delimiters, so what do you expect is a possible solution?

Comment: Oh. I got your point.